# how to efficiently detect and remove non-connecting lines in a shape

Tags: algorithm, polygon, point-in-polygon

I wish to perform a point-in-polygon check but first need to remove redundant lines from the polygon so that I can then carry out a ray-casting algorithm. The polygon is being represented in a 2D binary array (1 for filled, 0 for empty). Redundant lines are considered to have a point at either end that does not have at least 2 immediately adjacent cells filled (i.e. north, east, south and/or west but NOT diagonally).

Examples of lines with connected points (white = empty, blue = filled):

[image: connected1] [image: connected2]

Examples of lines ending with disconnected points (white = empty, blue = filled, green = filled but disconnected):

[image]
[image]

Example of polygon (white = empty, blue = filled, green = to remove):

[image: polygon1]
[image]

Example of polygon once redundant points have been removed (white = empty, blue = filled):

[image]

A simple but highly inefficient algorithm would be to detect points that have fewer than 2 adjacent filled points and remove those and loop until no changes have been made. What would be a more efficient way of going about this?

Side note: I am aware that a 2x2 (or larger) area of filled points will count as connected to each other so won't be removed - this is intentional. I am also aware that the ray-casting test will need to take into account horizontal and vertical lines for when I get as far as the ray-casting algorithm.

Comment: A [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) should work well for this.

Comment: @user3386109 as in perform a floodfill and use the filled region to detect which points are inside the polygon rather than removing redundant lines and using ray-tracing?

Comment: Nope. As in scan the array until you find a point on the polygon. Then use a flood fill to follow the points around the polygon. When you reach a dead end (only one adjacent cell), remove that cell. Then follow the dead end path backwards, deleting cells as you go.